# I want to add data-id="1" data-slug="home" to <li> in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu

actually i want create menu like this in wordpress, i am beginner in wordpress can any one guide how is it possible?

```
<ul>
 <li class="links-to-floor-li cv-active" data-id="1" data-slug="home"><a href="#home" class="fa fa-home tooltip-menu" title="HOME">Home</a>
            </li>
 <li class="links-to-floor-li" data-id="2" data-slug="about"><a href="#about" class="fa fa-user tooltip-menu" title="ABOUT">About</a>
            </li>
 <li class="links-to-floor-li" data-id="3" data-slug="resume"><a href="#resume" class="fa fa-graduation-cap tooltip-menu" title="RESUME">Resume</a>
            </li>
<li class="links-to-floor-li" data-id="4" data-slug="portfolio"><a href="#portfolio" class="fa fa-briefcase tooltip-menu" title="PORTFOLIO">Portfolio</a></li></ul>
```

my word press code is this

```
    <nav id="cv-main-menu">
           <?php
            $args = array(
                'theme_location'=> 'primary'
              );
          ?>


        <?php wp_nav_menu($args);  ?>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before printing, all menu items should run through a filter. You can use wp_nave_menu_items to tack items on to the menu:

```
// Filter wp_nav_menu() to add additional links and other output

function new_nav_menu_items($items) {
$homelink = '<li class="home"><a href="' . home_url( '/' ) . '">' . __('Home') . '</a> 
</li>';
// add the home link to the end of the menu
$items = $items . $homelink;
return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'new_nav_menu_items' );
```